# 404 NOT FOUND ruta con idioma Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, error404, idioma

tengo un problema con una ruta con el manejo de idiomas con laravel, al querer dirigirme a un programa académico con un id especifico, me envía "404| NOT FOUND, mi página principal funciona sin problemas http://mipagina.local/es/ mi código es el siguiente:
Vista blade

```
<a class="boton-leer" href="{{ route('programa_detalle',[ 'language'=>app()->getLocale(),'id'=>$programa->id_programa ]) }}"><strong>@lang('Leer M&aacute;s')</strong></a>
```

Archivo de rutas

```
Route::redirect('/','es');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function(){
    
    Route::get('/program/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\AcademicProgramController::class, 'getById'])->name("programa_detalle");

});
```

Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetLanguage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        \App::setLocale($request->language);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar php artisan route:list

```
|        | GET|HEAD                               | {language}/program/{id}                  | programa_detalle     | App\Http\Controllers\AcademicProgramController@getById       | web        |
```

La ruta que me manda error es: http://mipagina.local/es/program/15

Acabo de revisar el parametro que llega a getById() ( debería ser el $Id = 15 ) pero al colocar dd($id) me muestra el valor del lenguaje, porque será?

Me he respondido a mi propia pregunta, el error es en la función que ahora que le paso el parámetro de idioma también tengo que recogerlo y con eso me ha funcionado la ruta

Lo tenía así

```
public function getById($id){

        $record = $this->getRecord($id);
        return view('web.program', compact('record'));
   }
```

Y me ha funcionado así

```
public function getById($lang, $id){

        $record = $this->getRecord($id);
        return view('web.program', compact('record'));
   }
```

Comment: Exacto, el metodo del controlador debe tener, como mínimo, las mismas variables que le pasas por la ruta